# Import VM into AWS from Google Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I wonder how to import VM into AWS EC2 from Google Cloud ?
There is this doc :
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/

Am more worries about the potential issues.

Comment: I expect you export the Google Cloud VM, then import into AWS. GC says they don't export Windows instances.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one step solution would be using a third party tool to do it for you. There are way many cloud migration vendors that would make this process nearly zero effort.

I did that with CloudEndure and it went ok, but obviously it involves costs so make sure to check them out.